# How do i show recent posts first in Django blog?

Tags: django, date, blogs

I'm new Django, and i've been following a tutorial on creating a blog.

I've created a blog, that displays the posts. But, it displays the posts in the order: oldest posts first, and newest posts last.

This is the code in "models.py":

```
from django.db import models

class Blog(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    text = models.TextField()
```

How can i display the new posts first and the old posts last?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
from django.db import models

class Blog(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    text = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-date',]
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#meta-options

or do it with when you create the queryset

```
Blog.objects.all().order_by('-date')
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#order-by

Comment: the second one did the trick. But the first one gave me an Indentationerror when i synced the database.

Comment: You are probably using spaces to indent your lines; switch the tabs to spaces. The first solution is better then the second as it will keep the ordering consistent whenever you query the model

Comment: Yes, i realised that my indents were wrong, fixed it. I prefer the second because then it requires less work

Answer (score 1):

- This is how to work for me, not a new solution, only more detailed.
- in my **views.py**

```py
def blog(request):
    post_list = Post.objects.all().order_by('-timestamp')


    context = {
        'post_list': post_list,
    }
    return render(request, 'blog/blog.html', context)
```

- Thank you.